# Taking individual glyphs from another font in fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Can I tell `fontspec` to take individual glyphs from a different font? In particular I am interested in taking parentheses from an upright font when specifying the main italic font. (I suppose this might result in kerning problems, but so far I could not even try it out).

I searched the `fontspec` documentation, but did not find anything useful.

Comment: Assuming that you mean text fonts: You can do it with lualatex and the combofont package.

Comment: maybe have a look at the `embrac` package? This will replace the parentheses in emphasised text with upright ones.

Comment: @samcarter `embrac` has no effect on `\itshape`.